# Why is my delegate null?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I am building an iOS 6 app using XCode 4.5.1

I am trying to use a protocol which my controller can use to retrieve an image. However, my delegate is never called despite me calling it like this:

```
UIImage *image = [self.delegate mapViewController:self imageForAnnotation:aView.annotation];
```

When I debug this line I can see `self.delegate` is null, despite me associating a TableViewController to be its delegate.

MapViewController.h:

```
@class MapViewController;
@protocol MapViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
    - (UIImage *)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)sender imageForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
@end

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MapViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

MapViewController.m:

```
@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

I am using a TableViewController as the `MapViewControllerDelegate`:

```
@interface RecentPhotosTableViewController () <MapViewControllerDelegate>

- (PhotoViewController *) splitViewPhotoViewController;
@end

@implementation RecentPhotosTableViewController
- (UIImage *)mapViewController:(MapViewController *)sender imageForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    FlickrPhotoAnnotation *fpa = (FlickrPhotoAnnotation *)annotation;
    NSURL *url = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:fpa.photo format:FlickrPhotoFormatSquare];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    return data ? [UIImage imageWithData:data] : nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Where do you set the delegate?

Comment: I see no delegate assignments.

Comment: You indeed don't set the delegate. Btw, you can leave `@synthesize delegate = _delegate;` out since Xcode 4.4. The compiler will take care of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your code shows you setting anything as the delegate of anything else. You declare some properties and you adopt some protocols but none of that actually sets the `delegate` property of `self` to a value.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response Matt.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have all of your source code, of course, but Etan and CodaFi seem to be correct: where are the lines of code where you instantiate your `RecentPhotosTableViewController` object and set that object as your MapViewController object's delegate?

I think we're expecting to see something like:

```
@implementation RecentPhotosTableViewController

- (void) someMethod {
    self.mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    self.mapViewController.delegate = self;
    ...
}
```

You've declared a delegate property in the MapViewController class, but you have to actually set that delegate property to some object after instantiating it to make the delegate call work.

(Sorry if that's simplistic, but it seems like you're having a pretty basic conceptual difficulty; apologies if I've missed the point!)